# Linq get rows based on some conditions

Tags: c#, linq

Lets assume we have rows like this,

```
id       data1     data2     description    date
1          1         2           NULL        05/12/2014
2          3         3         Last Set      05/12/2014
3          1         2          Target       05/12/2014
4          0         0          Updated      05/12/2014
5          1         0       Revised Target  05/12/2014
```

Now what I want is to get latest out of the table by date first, but sometimes dates are same, so I need to get "Revised Target" but if there is no row for "Revised Target" then I need "Target" but if there is no row for target as well then I need "Target" but if there is no "Target" as well then I will take "Last Set".

So I am ignoring Updated and NULL ones here.

This is what I am trying but can't go any futther,

```
 var tar = (from m in table1 where m.Description != "Updated" &&  m.Description != NULL
                             select m).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).FirstOrDefault();
```

Please note i only need 1 row based on the conditions i explained.

**Edit**

I tried answer with most votes below I am getting error on IndexOf method as it not takes 1 argument...

Comment: you might want to replace `&` with `&&`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, just add another `Ordering`

Think you'll need multiple ternary if you're in `linq to entities`, you may use a Dictionary or something like that to make things clearer if you're in `linq to objects`.

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
.ThenBy(x => x.description == "RevisedTarget" 
             ? 0
             : (x.description == "Target" ? 1 :2)
 )
 .FirstOrDefault()
```

Answer (score 4):

So you're just missing the bit where you have some rules about which "description" to get, put these in an array in the order you want them

```
var descriptionOrder = new[]{"Revised Target","Target","Last Set"};
```

and use this to further order your results:

```
 var tar = (from m in table1 
            where m.Description != "Updated" &&  m.Description != null
            select m).OrderByDescending(x => x.Date)
            .ThenBy(x => Array.IndexOf(descriptionOrder,x.Description))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I was going to suggest using an Enum with a value, but this is much simpler.

Comment: Thank you, but it says no overload method IndexOf takes 1 argument :( , even though i added using system.linq

Comment: Try using `List<T>` then instead of an array. `List<T>.IndexOf` definitely only takes 1 argument.

Comment: @CustomizedName - what .NET framework version are you targeting?

Comment: @CustomizedName - Ok, I must be losing the plot - see update. You're right you cant call `IndexOf` like I did. Too much javascript ive forgotton my C#!

Answer (score 0):

`Case when` ordering in Linq

```
 var tar = table1.Where(x=>x.description != null && x.description != "Updated")
            .OrderByDescending(x=>x.description == "Revised Target" ? 3 : 0)
            .ThenByDescending(x=>x.description == "Target" ? 2 : 0)
            .ThenByDescending(x=>x.description =="Last Set" ? 1 :0)
            .ThenByDescending(x=>x.date)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```